# Can a wine have an animalic facet on the nose or palate?

Tags: wine

I come from a perfumery background with very little experience with wine. When I have heard tasting notes, they have been fairly unsurprising from the fruity to floral to green.

However, I have been curious if there are wines with a clearly perceptible animalic note, either on the nose or on the palate. By animalic, I don't mean just hay like (which is associated with animalic scents) but raunchy in the way that ingredients like castoreum or civet are for example. I also think of narcissus and cassie which have cresols that are in the odor of pigs as well.

I imagine if a wine has this undertone it's not something a sommelier would talk about to a customer and so I haven't heard it discussed even in a Michelin restaurant setting.

Is it possible for a wine to have this, and if so, can you make some recommendations (up to an approximate price of say, 200 EUR for a bottle)?

Comment: A sommelier would probably talk about "*scents of wood and musk, or wild game*". But it's often a plus for wines served with dishes where you have wild boar or deer for instance, even strong cheeses. Tasted some in France with Auxey-Duresses, or Aloxe-Corton (or some other wines from "*Côtes de Nuits*"). This unique terroir produces wines with strong scents and taste and could fit your search maybe? Prices range from €30 to €250++ though